# Using the "LIKE" with the "=" criterion together

Tags: php, mysql, search

I do not know how I can intergrate the "=" criteria with the "LIKE" in the following piece of code.

The code is for searching with multiple criterion. The search with this cat_id is okey expect that I want its criteria not to be part of the "LIKE" criteria; instead it should be "=" so that I can get the exact match in the search. Your help will be appreciated.

```
$criteria = array('ctitle', 'csubject', 'creference', 'cat_id', 'cmaterial', 'ctechnic', 'cartist', 'csource', 'stolen');
$likes = "";
$url_criteria = '';
foreach ( $criteria AS $criterion ) {
        if ( ! empty($_POST[$criterion]) ) {
                $value = ($_POST[$criterion]);
                switch ($criterion) {
                    case 'cat_id':
                        $likes .= " AND `$criterion`='$value'";
                        break;

                    default:
                        $likes .= " AND `$criterion` LIKE '%$value%'";
                        break;
                $url_criteria .= '&amp;'.$criterion.'='.htmlentities($_POST[$criterion]);
            } }
        } elseif ( ! empty($_GET[$criterion]) ) {
                $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[$criterion]);
                switch ($criterion) {
                    case 'cat_id':
                        $likes .= " AND `$criterion`='$value'";
                        break;

                    default:
                        $likes .= " AND `$criterion` LIKE '%$value%'";
                        break;
                $url_criteria .= '&amp;'.$criterion.'='.htmlentities($_GET[$criterion]);
        } //var_dump($likes);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM collections WHERE c_id>0" . $likes . " ORDER BY c_id ASC";
```

Comment: Your script may be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: ...is definitely vulnerable to SQL injection.  Use `$value = mysql_real_escape_string($value)`.

Comment: @Zenexer The `mysql_*` family of functions [have been deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) ever since PHP developers proved they didn't know how to work with a database safely. So like, forever, basically.

Comment: Ok, at this moment, I just want to know the logic of combining the LIKE with the =. I know I will have a long time to learn this in mysqli/PDO. Can you help?

Comment: @ta.speot.is Yeah, I use mysqli, but we all know everyone still uses the functions.

Comment: @Zenexer No, it may not be vulnerable if magic quotes are enabled. But you shouldn’t rely on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`switch` is your friend.

```
$criteria = array('ctitle', 'csubject', 'creference', 'cat_id', 'cmaterial', 'ctechnic', 'cartist', 'csource', 'stolen');
$likes = "";
$url_criteria = '';
foreach ($criteria as $criterion) {
        if (isset($_POST[$criterion]) && !empty($_POST[$criterion])) {
                $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$criterion]);
                switch ($criterion) {
                    case 'cat_id':
                        $likes .= " AND `$criterion`='$value'";
                        break;

                    default:
                        $likes .= " AND `$criterion` LIKE '%$value%'";
                        break;
                }
```

Better'n `if` statement or ternary operator because it's easy to expand in the future.

Comment: Hi Zenexer, I have just updated my first post to include the rest of the code. In case I might miss something important.

Comment: I've fixed a typo in your code. Also, you'd need to escape `%`, `_` as well as backslashes in `$value` in the switch's default branch.

Comment: I updated using the switch, but I am getting an error unexpected T_ELSEIF.

Comment: @JosephBupe You have an extra closing brace on the line before `elseif`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if($criterion=='cat_id')
        $likes .= " AND `$criterion` = '$value'"
    else
        $likes .= " AND `$criterion` LIKE '%$value%'";
```